# How to display split mysql result 100 in to multiples of 10

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to display mysql database result in a limit, but i want to display like this for ex.i have 100 records mysql result in database, but i want to display 10 in each page, and navigate to next result using page no at the bottom of the page in resultant table like .1/2/3 dynamically,page "1" will display 1-10, "2" table content changed to 11-20, "3rd" click 21-30 in the table.

Comment: How many of the millions of pagination tutorials have you failed to find when you googled this?

Comment: i am not getting exact suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` has an offset value that can be used to calculate how many rows should be "skipped"

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 10, 0
-- display ten rows starting from row 0

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 10, 10
-- display ten rows starting from row 10

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 10, 20 
-- display ten rows starting from row 20 ...
```

etc.
So you'd need to calculate your page offset by (CurrentPage-1)*10